# Laravel: How to display multiple upload images or videos in same div like facebook

Tags: laravel

How can i display multiple  pictures or videos in single or same div like facebook..because i want to upload multiple pictures in the same time and post or display like collage or like album like facebook.

Who can help me? please?  I want to know how to do that.

Comment: display like collage or like album same at facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugin called dropzone.

Or

If you just want to display picture as an album just use foreach loop and display all pictures as an gallery. Then you could use multiple file upload form to upload your pictures. At the back end you can validate the pictures.